# Change of Basis: Incorrect Equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's suppose we have a linear transformation $A$, a vector $\vec{v}$ and a vector $\vec{w}$ where $A\vec{v} = \vec{w}$ and a basis $B$.
My source has given me the following equation
$$\vec{w}_B = A\vec{v}_B \: (\vec{w}_B = \vec{c} \: \text{such that} \: B\vec{c} = \vec{w})$$
However, through some algebraic manipulation we find:
$$\vec{w}_B = A\vec{v}_B$$
$$B^{-1}\vec{w} = A(B^{-1}\vec{v})$$
$$B^{-1}(A\vec{v}) = A(B^{-1}\vec{v})$$
while the two sides of the equation share the same terms, matrix multiplication is not always commutative. Did I make a mistake or is the original equation incorrect?

Comment: I will say: matrix multiplication is not generally commutative, but for specific matrices the product may commute.

Comment: @Dave Yes, but I have tried this with some examples and it does not seem to hold consistantly

Comment: My comment was more a comment on just "matrix multiplication is not always commutative".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is a linear transformation, but how it is represented as a matrix will depend on which basis you are using.

If $w = Av$, then one usually writes $w_B = A_B v_B$ where $A_B$ is the matrix representation of the linear transformation $A$ with respect to basis $B$. You can check that $A_B = B^{-1} A B$.

I'm not sure why your source wrote it that way; it may be that there is some setup/context that might explain that notation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for a  day now!